# How to transfer a conda environment to an off-line computer

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, conda

I have a conda environment at home that I'm using on my Ph.D., but now that I'm needing more computational power I have to transfer (or install a perfect copy) of my environment on one of the University's computers. The computers have no internet connection, all I have is SSH.

My attempt to copy the entire /anaconda3 directory and .bashrc to a path similar to the one I use at my home (/home/henrique/bin) have not worked.

What is the correct way to transfer my anaconda install?

Comment: You know that the `.bashrc` file have to be in `/home/henrique`, right? Have you checked is the PATH environment variable is correctly set on your new location?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Conda-pack is a command line tool that archives a conda environment, which includes all the binaries of the packages installed in the environment. This is useful when you want to reproduce an environment with limited or no internet access. All the previous methods download packages from their respective repositories to create an environment. Keep in mind that conda-pack is both platform and operating system specific and that the target computer must have the same platform and OS as the source computer.

To install conda-pack, make sure you are in the root or base environment so that it is available in sub-environments. Conda-pack is available at conda-forge or PyPI.
conda-forge:

```
conda install -c conda-forge conda-pack
```

PyPI:

```
pip install conda-pack
```

To package an environment:

```
# Pack environment my_env into my_env.tar.gz
$ conda pack -n my_env

# Pack environment my_env into out_name.tar.gz
$ conda pack -n my_env -o out_name.tar.gz

# Pack environment located at an explicit path into my_env.tar.gz
$ conda pack -p /explicit/path/to/my_env
```

To install the environment:

```
# Unpack environment into directory `my_env`
$ mkdir -p my_env
$ tar -xzf my_env.tar.gz -C my_env

# Use Python without activating or fixing the prefixes. Most Python
# libraries will work fine, but things that require prefix cleanups
# will fail.
$ ./my_env/bin/python

# Activate the environment. This adds `my_env/bin` to your path
$ source my_env/bin/activate

# Run Python from in the environment
(my_env) $ python

# Cleanup prefixes from in the active environment.
# Note that this command can also be run without activating the environment
# as long as some version of Python is already installed on the machine.
(my_env) $ conda-unpack
```

[Source](https://www.anaconda.com/moving-conda-environments/)

Comment: What does "cleanup prefixes" mean?  What is actually done when the  prefixes are cleaned up?